# How to optimally group based on correlation statistic using python?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have a python list of about 300 items in a pandas correlation matrix and for each item, I would like to programmatically group the corresponding 10 least correlated items with it and store it in a dictionary.

I'm not sure how to do that since the correlations run from 1 to -1.  If I take the smallest number, I'll take the most negatively correlated items.

I'm sure this is some sort of iterator but I'm not sure how.  Here is a smaller correlation matrix example with 10.

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {'index':['XBI','SDOW','IYG','DRIP','SCHV','TNA','SIL','IEMG','GUSH','USL'],
'XBI':[1.000,-0.605,0.546,-0.424,0.610,0.716,0.215,0.485,0.453,0.265],
'SDOW':[-0.605,1.000,-0.890,0.554,-0.965,-0.871,-0.256,-0.772,-0.595,-0.429,],
'IYG':[0.546,-0.890,1.000,-0.567,0.918,0.838,0.197,0.701,0.603,0.325],
'DRIP':[-0.424,0.554,-0.567,1.000,-0.583,-0.609,-0.265,-0.530,-0.972,-0.686],
'SCHV':[0.610,-0.965,0.918,-0.583,1.000,0.893,0.276,0.768,0.624,0.431],
'TNA':[0.716,-0.871,0.838,-0.609,0.893,1.000,0.302,0.714,0.648,0.421],
'SIL':[0.215,-0.256,0.197,-0.265,0.276,0.302,1.000,0.317,0.227,0.308],
'IEMG':[0.485,-0.772,0.701,-0.530,0.768,0.714,0.317,1.000,0.567,0.399],
'GUSH':[0.453,-0.595,0.603,-0.972,0.624,0.648,0.227,0.567,1.000,0.675],
'USL':[0.265,-0.429,0.325,-0.686,0.431,0.421,0.308,0.399,0.675,1.000]}

matrix = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)
matrix = matrix.set_index('index')
```

How would we take this small example and produce a dictionary for each symbol in the index as a a key and the value being a list of 3 of the least correlated items?

End result would look like this for the first two symbols:

`{'XBI':['SIL','USL','DRIP'], 'SDOW':['SIL','USL','DRIP']}`

In happens that the first two would have the same list....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `abs` + `nsmallest` inside a `dict` comprehension:

```
dct = {c:matrix[c].abs().nsmallest(3).index.tolist() for c in matrix}
```

---

```
{'XBI': ['SIL', 'USL', 'DRIP'],
 'SDOW': ['SIL', 'USL', 'DRIP'],
 'IYG': ['SIL', 'USL', 'XBI'],
 'DRIP': ['SIL', 'XBI', 'IEMG'],
 'SCHV': ['SIL', 'USL', 'DRIP'],
 'TNA': ['SIL', 'USL', 'DRIP'],
 'SIL': ['IYG', 'XBI', 'GUSH'],
 'IEMG': ['SIL', 'USL', 'XBI'],
 'GUSH': ['SIL', 'XBI', 'IEMG'],
 'USL': ['XBI', 'SIL', 'IYG']}
```